# keep only social login custom option in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, authentication, woocommerce

I install Plugin Woocommerce Social login from code canyon. And after we select product to add to cart, the customer have to choice which is manually login or using Social Login button.  I would like customer to just have one choice which is using social login only instead of manually login.

You can see here, the two option of login enabled by Woocommerce Social login plugin:

[image: Two option of login]

How to remove Woocommerce default login form keeping the social login button functionality?

Answer (score 1):

To make customizations, you can override Woocommerce templates via your theme… First reed the following documentation, that explain how you can do that:

[Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

**The related template to override is:** [`myaccount/form-login.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.5/templates/myaccount/form-login.php)

Once you have copied `form-login.php` template from woocommerce plugin to your active themes's "woocommerce" folder, in a "myaccount" subfolder:

1. open edit it
2. remove the code from line 38 to line 58 (all the code inside the `<form>` tags).
3. save

That should only keep your "Two options social login form".